# Multiprocessing pool in python

Tags: python, pool

I have this code which works when I use python in interactive mode, but then when I save it as example.py and try to run it does not work. Why is that?

```
import numpy as np
from multiprocessing import Pool

def wrap(args):
        sc=np.zeros(2)
        n=args[0]
        r0=args[1]
        rf=args[2]
        sc[0]=1. #other complicated funcion not important here
        sc[1]=2. #other complicated funcion not important here
        return sc

def Scp(n,photozname,zbin):
        phi=np.genfromtxt(photozname)
        x=phi[phi[:,0]>(zbin*0.5),0]
        y=phi[phi[:,0]>(zbin*0.5),1]
        N=len(x)
        args = [(n,x[i],y[i]) for i in range(N)]
        if __name__ == "__main__":
                pool = Pool(processes=80)
                out=pool.map(wrap,args)
                pool.terminate()
        sc=np.array(out)
        s3c=np.sum(sc[:,0]*y)
        s4c=np.sum(sc[:,1]*y)
        return s3c,s4c

s3c,s4c=Scp(n,file,zbin)
```

Comment: Could you explain what "does not work" means? Do you get the wrong result? Do you get an error? Do the tectonic plates start to move?

Comment: in your code, statement s3c,s4c=Scp(n,file,zbin) it simply calls the function Scp() and the returned values are assigned to s3c and s4c. what do you want to do further with these objects s3c and s4c. while running directly it simply calls Scp() and assigns returned value to s3c and s4c and exits. the problem is you are getting no output as you wanted. am i right?

Comment: a last line `print s3c, s4c` is missing?! non [reproductible problem](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: By not working I mean that it jumps the paralelization and says that out is not defined. And when I do it interactively everything works fine.

Comment: yes, a print s3c, s4c would be missing, but that is not the problem